# Nginx on wlan passing only index file

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, wifi

**I have a local Wordpress site running on Nginx.** 
What I am trying to do is to make it run over Wlan, so far I have managed this:

```
1. Made site running on local computer.

2. Run the site on other computer that is connected to the same router.
```

The problem is that when I try to run this site on other computer it serves only index file.

The computer ip I tried to run the site on is **192.xxx.x.1** and server ip is **192.xxx.x.3**

The error in browser from **192.xxx.x.1** machine:

*GET http://localhost/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/style.css*

How can I configure Nginx so when I run site outside local server machine it gets all the files from

192.xxx.x.3/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/style.css*

instead of

localhost/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/style.css*

**My Nginx site config:**

```html
server {
        listen 192.xxx.x.3:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/wordpress;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                
        }

}
```

Comment: It looks like a WordPress problem. Have you set SITE URL and HOME to `localhost`?

Comment: Thanks, was so focused on nginx that I forgot about Wordpress configuration. Changed localhost to ip and now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like a WordPress problem. Have you set SITE URL and HOME to
>   localhost? – Richard Smith 20 hours ago